# ¿Como puedo renombrar una base de datos en android?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Lo que sucede es que al principio
La base de datos la nombre sin la extensión ".db" y al momento de revisar en data no me aparece pero si creo una nueva con la extension ".db" si me aparece, esto es incomodo porque no puedo ver lo que esta ocurriendo en la db. Alguien sabe como renombrar la base de datos en sqlite de android?

```
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BDPersons";

    String tablaPerson = "create table person(" +
            "id varchar(100) primary key," +
            "nombre varchar(30))";


    public BaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(tablaPerson);
    }
```

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor, tu clase SQLiteOpenHelper como estas creando la base de datos. Si la renombras puede ser que tu aplicación no funcione correctamente. Tal vez solo necesites generar un base de datos con la extensión correcta.

Comment: gracias @goku venz revisa lo que comento acerca de la variable DATABASE_NAME  en mi respuesta, es importante eliminar el caché de la aplicación, borrar la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Tendras crear un nuevo archivo, copiar de la vieja db ese archivo y luego eliminar la vieja db. Esto se haría creando un archivo con la extension que deseas, renombrar la nueva db al nombre de la nueva utilizando [`File#renameTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)) y luego borras la vieja:

```
public void renombrarDbSiRequerido(String nombreArchivoViejaDb, String nuevoArchivoDb)
{
    File viejaDb = new File(nombreArchivoVieajDb);
    File nuevaDb = new File(nuevoArchivoDb);

     // verificamos ya fue creado el nuevo archivo para db
    if(!nuevaDb .exists())
    {
       // como no existe, procedemos a crear el nuevo archivo de la db
       nuevaDb.createFile();

       // renombramos la vieja por el nuevo
       viejaDb.renameTo(nuevaDb);
    }
}
```

Donde el parametro `nombreArchivoViejaDb` es la ruta completa de la db que quieres renombrar y el parametro `nuevoArchivoDb` es la ruta completa del nuevo nombre;

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas tu clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper` puedes ver la variable    `DATABASE_NAME` donde puedes renombrar su valor agregando la extensión:

```
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BDPersons.db";
```

este valor de la variable lo puedes renombrar y agregar la extensión, de esta forma tu aplicación seguirá funcionando sin problema y podrás ver tu archivo identificado como una base de datos ya que fue creado con la extensión ".db".

```
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BDPersons.db"; //*

    String tablaPerson = "create table person(" +
            "id varchar(100) primary key," +
            "nombre varchar(30))";


    public BaseDatos(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(tablaPerson);
    }
```

**Es importante eliminar el caché de la aplicación, borrar la aplicación o cambiar el valor de `DATABASE_VERSION` para que veas el cambio reflejado en tu Base de datos.**

Comment: el problema con esa solución es que se crea una nueva base de datos  vacía y la anterior bd siguen estando ahí los datos, eso en produccion no seria bueno

Comment: No deja una bd vacía, elimina la aplicación y subela con el cambio, en realidad en producción la bd se generaría con el nombre BDPersons.db , private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BDPersons.db";

Comment: Como se que los datos de los usuarios no se eliminaran al lanzar esa actualizacion

Comment: goku, cuando salga a producción tu aplicación crearía una BD llamada "BDPersons.db" y se mantendria siempre, a menos que tu decides renombrarla nuevamente que no creo sea necesario durante la vida de tu aplicación. Lo que puede cambiar es la estructura de tablas, por ejemplo cuando agregas un nuevo campo.